# NSFetchedResultsController performance issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tab bar controller with 5 tabs. Each tab has a table view controller. Two of those are NSFetchedResultsControllers.

Whenever the user taps on an item in the table view, the item first gets saved to history and then gets segued to and displayed. One of those NSFetchedResultsControllers displays the history of viewed items, ordered by date.

When none of those NSFetchedResultsControllers have been lazily instantiated, the performance is fine:

```
13:41:50.485 Saving to history…
13:41:50.487 CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
13:41:50.490 CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZSLBOOK SET ZDATEADDEDTOHISTORY = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
13:41:50.495 CoreData: sql: COMMIT
13:41:50.511 Saved
```

But after the NSFetchedResultsControllers responsible for showing the history gets instantiated, the speed gets reduced dramatically, taking one to two seconds (plus rendering the next view), so the app seems to hang.

```
13:42:08.750 Saving to history…
13:42:08.752 Will change
13:42:08.753 Object changed
13:42:09.579 Did change
13:42:09.594 CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
13:42:09.596 CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZSLBOOK SET ZCOVERIMAGE = ?, ZDATEADDEDTOHISTORY = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
13:42:09.619 CoreData: sql: COMMIT
13:42:09.637 Saved
```

Just for you to know what's going on, here is my code for updating history:

```
- (void)addToHistory
{
    NSLog(@"Saving to history…");
    self.book.dateAddedToHistory = [NSDate date];
    NSError *error;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    NSLog(@"Saved");
}
```

The log messages are called in these methods:

```
controllerWillChangeContent ("Will change")
controller:didChangeObject ("Object changed")
controllerDidChangeContent ("Did change")
```

The NSFetchedResultsController is implemented standardly. The performance is sluggish even when I have only a few rows (5–10). Core Data is fine (it is very fast as you can see from the logs), I set batch size to 20, have indexes etc. So the problem lies somewhere in the NSFetchedResultsController.

One of the possibilities is to set the TVC's fetched results controller delegate to nil. But then it is quite hard to manage the updates, select the row and scroll to the last position (because you need to reload the data).

Do you have any ideas what could be causing the problem? I don't believe this performance is regular, since a table with a bazillion rows gets loaded and displayed in a split second.

Comment: Have you run this under instruments to see where time is being spent? Usually it's on processChanges notification methods.

Comment: Yep, that is true, most of the time is spent in postNotificationName:object:userInfo. It seems like it is redrawing and animating the table in the background. This subprocess is taking the most time: -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded].

Answer (score 0):

You can completely avoid using an NSFetchedResultsController by using the free Sensible TableView framework. The framework will automatically fetch your data and display it on the table views, including generating all the detail view UI and relationship views. In my experience, this has been much more efficient than using an NSFetchedResultsController in the past.